# Zooming in on raster file in R

Tags: raster, r, zoom

I used the nsidcICE function located here: https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/nsidcICE.R and the following code to open a sea ice raster file. However, I would like to overlap vector points and "zoom in" on the raster to the Canadian Arctic (lat: 72 to 75, long: -90 to -80). I am new to R and GIS.

```
library(raster)
library(graticule)
library(rgdal)

tfile <- system.file("extdata",  "nt_20140728_f17_v1.1_n.bin", package = "graticule")
ice<-.rasterFromNSIDCFile("nt_20140728_f17_v1.1_n.bin")


meridians <- seq(-180, 160, by = 20)
parallels <- c(-80, -73.77, -68, -55, -45)
mlim <- c(-180, 180)
plim <- c(-88, -50)
grat <- graticule(lons = meridians, lats = parallels, xlim = mlim, ylim =     plim, proj = projection(ice))
labs <- graticule_labels(meridians, parallels, xline = -45, yline = -60, proj = projection(ice))
plot(ice, axes = FALSE)
plot(grat, add = TRUE, lty = 3)
text(labs, lab = parse(text= labs$lab), col= c("firebrick", "darkblue")[labs$islon + 1], cex = 0.85)
title(sprintf("Sea ice concentration %s", gsub(".bin", "", basename(ice))), cex.main = 0.8) 
title(sub = projection(ice), cex.sub = 0.6)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Then please [edit] your question to clarify where you are having trouble and on the results of any research you have done in an effort to try to answer the question.

Comment: You are brave using that function!  I need to update it to allow use of later version files. BTW, you need parallels and plim that are *positive*.

Answer (score 2):

The NSIDC ice is in (north) Polar Stereographic, the easiest way to get a zoom is to use `drawExtent()` on the current plot, then use that to set up the plot

```
## <your plot above>
e <- drawExtent() ## interactive!
plot(e, asp = 1, xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE)
plot(ice, add = TRUE)
## the rest of <your plot above>
```

Note that I had to negate your parallels, they should be positive for the northern hemisphere (indicated by "_n" in the file name, and the "+lat_0" and "+lat_ts" in the `projection(ice)`.

Alternatively, use `projectExtent` to discover the right xlim/ylim:

```
llex <- extent(-90, 80,  72, 75)
ppex <- projectExtent(raster(llex, crs = "+proj=longlat"), projection(ice))
plot(crop(ice), axes = FALSE)
## <the rest of your plot above>
```

I see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
plot(ice, axes = FALSE, xlim = c(-90,-80), ylim = c(72, 75))
plot(grat, add = TRUE, lty = 3, xlim = c(-90,-80), ylim = c(72, 75))
```

the `xlim()` and `ylim()` parameters allow you to customise the boundaries of your plot.

Comment: This can't work because the data is in polar stereographic, xlim and ylim don't map trivially to ranges in long/lat, and they are required units that are in metres (0, 0  is at the north pole for this file).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the ***zoom*** package. I tried it with raster data from a satellite image and it worked nicely. You can use the function *zm()* after plotting your full map, then zoom in by right clicking into the area you are interested. It is not very focused but it works as a quick solution for getting a quick overview. There is also no interpolation of the view, as you would have like in a GIS. HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all your computing on that region, you may use the function `raster::crop(your_raster_object, your_vector_object)`; `raster::extent(raster_or_vector_object)` returns the bounding box of a geospatial object, which allows to add easily as if it were a buffer, e.g. `extent(a_vector_in_utm) + 100`  will add 100 m to the bounding box.

There's a manual way to zoom into a raster or spatial object plotted in R, `raster::select(first_raster)`, then you draw a rectangle covering the region you want in the plot and you get the subset of the larger raster.